# UB в невыполняемом коде

Tags: c++

```
int foo() {
  int* ptr = nullptr;
  return *ptr;
}

int main(){
  return 0;
}
```

Содержит ли эта программа `UB`? Функция `foo` не вызывается.

Comment: У вопроса должно быть нормальное "говорящее" название, чтобы было понятно о чем он

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нет, эта программа не приводит к неопределенному поведению (англ. undefined behavior, UB).

Поведение становится неопределенным ровно тогда, когда выполнение доходит до момента, после которого будет неизбежно выполнено действие, которое, согласно стандарту, вызывает это самое неопределенное поведение.*

В этом коде такого не произойдет никогда, соответственно никакого UB в нем нет.

---

<sup>*</sup> Дополнительно, если любой запуск программы неизбежно приводит к UB, компилятор вправе отказаться ее компилировать, выдав соответствующее сообщение.

Также, поведение считается неопределенным при запуске любой "ill-formed, no diagnostic required" программы, если она вообще скомпилировалась.

---

Связанная дискуссия  на английском SO:
[Can branches with undefined behavior be assumed unreachable and optimized as dead code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23153445/can-branches-with-undefined-behavior-be-assumed-unreachable-and-optimized-as-dea)

Верхний ответ подтверждает мои слова, и там же можно найти соответствующие ссылки на стандарт:

> So, an unreachable statement with UB doesn't give the program UB. A reachable statement that (because of the values of inputs) is never reached, doesn't give the program UB.

и

> if [...] UB does occur, then it can easily affect a statement "before" the UB statement.

Comment: Эта программа действительно не приводит к неопределенному поведению. Однако последующие утверждения совершенно не верны. Если программа содержит неопределенное поведение, то допустимым проявлением такого неопределенного поведения является отказ компилятора компилировать код. Т.е. неопределенное поведение может проявляться еще на стадии компиляции.

Comment: @AnT Можно какую-нибудь ссылку по *"допустимым проявлением такого неопределенного поведения является отказ компилятора компилировать код"*? Для "ill-formed, NDR" это логично, а про UB я такого не слышал.

Comment: "Terms and definitions" (http://eel.is/c++draft/intro.defs#defns.undefined): "...Permissible undefined behavior ranges from ignoring the situation completely with unpredictable results, to behaving during translation or program execution in a documented manner characteristic of the environment (with or without the issuance of a diagnostic message), to terminating a translation or execution (with the issuance of a diagnostic message)..."

Comment: Я думаю, что я не прав насчет "не приводит к неопределенному поведению". Разрешение на "отказ транслировать" сделано именно для случаев, когда компилятор "не знает" как транслировать код с UB. А это не требует вызываемости кода. Главное - чтобы код был в evaluated context.

Comment: @AnT *"сделано именно для случаев, когда компилятор "не знает" как транслировать код с UB"* Если компилятор наткнется на такой код, который он не знает, как транслировать, то разве он не может просто поставить на этом моменте, скажем, вызов `abort();`? Вживую я, конечно, такого не видел, но стандарту бы соответствовало.

Comment: @AnT Вот что нашел: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23153445/can-branches-with-undefined-behavior-be-assumed-unreachable-and-optimized-as-dea В принятом ответе написано примерно то же, что у меня: *"an unreachable statement with UB doesn't give the program UB. A reachable statement that (because of the values of inputs) is never reached, doesn't give the program UB"* и *"if [...] UB does occur, then it can easily affect a statement "before" the UB statement"*.

Comment: Может. Или просто выкинуть код. Интересный пример: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4bf71de26f087976. GCC разворачивает цикл, обнаруживает UB на второй итерации и ничего не говоря выкидывает ее нафиг. Код печатает `1`. Но проявляется это только тогда, когда `N` объявлена на уровне файла. Если `N` локальна, GCC ругается по UB предупреждением, но итерацию не выкидывает. Код печатает `2`.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat По-моему нет никаких оснований полагаться на недостижимость этой функции. Во-первых потому, что она имеет extern линковку и по-любому должна компилироваться в условиях, когда подразумевается что она может быть вызвана из других единиц трансляции. А во-вторых потому что это получается сильно завязано на конкретные особенности компилятора. Вот в [статье llvm блог](http://blog.llvm.org/2011/05/what-every-c-programmer-should-know_14.html) красочно описывается, что получается, если меняется порядок проходов отбрасывания недостижимого кода и устранения лишних проверок указателей.

Comment: @VTT *"по-любому должна компилироваться"* Должна, но у компилятора, насколько я понимаю, нет оснований ломать что-то снаружи этой функции (UB происходит только если ее вызвать). *"сильно завязано на конкретные особенности компилятора, ... [ссылка]"* Мне кажется, принцип "если UB неизбежно, программа может сломаться не доходя до него" как раз объясняет примеры по ссылке.

Comment: При наличии UB компилятору разрешено ломать сразу все. А вот никакого анализа достижимости участка кода с UB он как раз выполнять не обязан. В стандарте даже вроде как и нет такого понятия, как "достижимость". А цитата "if any such execution contains an undefined operation..." только подчеркивает, что поведение не определено не только непосредственно для конкретной операции, но и для операций, которые могли быть осуществлены еще до первого ее вызова.

Comment: По-моему интерпретировать эту цитату в том смысле, что "если при выполнении программы операция, поведение которой не определено, никогда не выполняется, то программа не содержит неопеределенного поведения" не верно. А вот то, само наличие в коде операции, поведение которой не определено, - это уже гарантированное неопределенное поведение.

Comment: @VTT Признаю, что железобетонных аргументов в поддержку моего ответа у меня нет, но дальше копать стандарт мне что-то не хочется. Пожалуй, я поверю консенсусу англоговорящих коллег. :)

Answer (score 1):

Да, это программа содержит Неопределенное Поведение. Соответственно результат компиляции и выполнения этой программы стандартом не задается. Компилятор вправе вообще ее не компилировать (что делает VS например) или создать нерабочий бинарик. Проявление UB нельзя считать локализованным или зависящим выполнения проблемного участка.

Контрпример. Здесь неопределенного поведения нет, так препроцессор вырежет функцию из текста единицы трансляции:

```
#ifdef NOT_DEFINED
int foo() {
  int* ptr = nullptr;
  return *ptr;
}
#endif

int main(){
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Похоже, придется нам закапываться в стандарт и разбираться, что на самом деле там написано.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Что у вас никогда не было проблем с UB в невыполняемом коде? Вон хотя бы тот же пропущенный `return` ломавший кодогенерацию в студии.

Comment: Не-а, не было. :)

Comment: Да, интересно... Отказ компилировать код с забытым `return` - вполне легитимное проявление UB. Но как быть с невызываемыми функциями?...

Comment: @AnT Ну как, функция же с external линковкой, должна быть скомпилирована по-любому, вполне логично, что на этом моменте компилятор может запнуться об разыменование нулевого указателя и до момента, когда станет понятно, что эта функция на самом деле никогда не вызывается и ее можно выбросить, может даже не дойти.

Comment: А какая версия VS отказывается компилировать? На [rextester собирает успешно](https://rextester.com/EMZEY90040).

Comment: @älёxölüt VS2017 с включенным анализом. Это несколько притянутый пример, но тем не менее.